# asp.net mvc не освобождается память после передачи файла клиенту

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, видео, кэширование

Есть вот такой код:

```
    // специально отключил кэширование возвращаемых данных
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetVideo(string path)
    {            
        byte[] data = await _fileService.GetFileAsync(path);                        
        if (data == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return File(data, "video/mp4");
    }
```

Всё очень просто - получаем `byte[]`  из метода `GetFileAsync` и передаём на клиент. На клиенте есть несколько тегов `video`, которые обращаются к `GetVideo`  и получают оттуда несколько довольно больших видео (мегабайт по 500) общим размером примерно 3-4 Гб. После того, как страница загрузилась, а запросы к `GetVideo` успешно выполнились, я вижу, что процесс w3wp.exe на сервере отжирает те самые 3-4 Гб памяти. Насколько я понимаю, они должны были освободиться после того, как данные были отправлены клиенту, но почему-то процесс постоянно занимает эту память. Кэширование, как и указано в коде, я отключил. 
Кроме того, проблема, очевидно, не в строке

```
byte[] data = await _fileService.GetFileAsync(path);
```

потому что после того, как я заменил её на строку

```
byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(path));
```

эта проблема всё равно осталась. Иными словами, память в методе `GetFileAsync` не течёт. Как побороть эту проблему и вернуть память обратно системе после того, как данные отправлены клиенту?

Comment: Память освобождается когда GC её освобождает, а не когда что то куда то передается. А GC её освобождает, когда ему захочется или когда вы его явно попросите.

Comment: @tym32167 я знаю, что память освобождает сборщик мусора, руководствуясь своей внутренней логикой. Проблема в том, что эти байты в памяти  уже не нужны приложению - запрос выполнен, ответ на него ушел клиенту. Отсюда и вопрос: почему эти гигабайты (гигабайты, Карл!) по-прежнему висят в памяти, при том, что кэширование отключено. И висят они до тех пор пока я не перезагружаю IIS

Comment: Массив байт скорее всего попал в LOH (Large Object Heap). Что это такое и как его очистить/уплотнить, и когда стоит это делать можно почитать тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx . Если это не поможет, берите профилировщик памяти (например dotMemory) и ищите утечку.

Comment: @Pupkin сборка мусора недетерминирована . т.е. память освобождается не сразу же, как станет ненужна, а неизвестно когда. и вообще - даже если GC соберет мусор - это еще не означает, что рантайм решит отпустить эту память системе - это ведь виртуальная память, а реальная память на планках, зачем ее отпускать, если вашему приложению она еще может понадобиться (вдруг еще один запрос с файлом придет!)